# Find managers having employees making the highest average salary

Tags: sql

I was trying to use the RANK() function to list the names of the
managers whose employees having the highest average salaries.
I searched others' posts and looked up RANK() function.
My code is as below. 
I got the "FROM keyword not found when expected".

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.
The task required to use RANK() or ROWNUM function.

```
select e.employee_id, e.salary, m.first_name, m.last_name, m.employee_id,m.salary, Rank() over (Order by m.salary) salary_rank from RITDB_employee e, RITDB_manager m WHERE e.salary>(select salary_rank=1 FROM RITDB_manager m INNER JOIN RITDB_employee e ON e.employee_id=m.employee_id)
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results.  Also, an appropriate database tag would help.

Comment: mentioning ROWNUM in the question suggest you are using Oracle database?

Comment: @RaymondNijland Yes. I apologize for any unprofessional parts, as I am a bit new to SQL..

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry for the late reply. I am using Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the ranks of the *managers*

```
select m.first_name, m.last_name, m.employee_id,
       avg(e.salary) as avg_employee_salary,
       rank() over (order by avg(e.salary)) as employee_salary_rak 
from RITDB_employee e join
     RITDB_manager m 
     on e.employee_id=m.employee_id
group by m.first_name, m.last_name, m.employee_id
order by avg_employee_salary desc;
```

You can use a subquery if you want to find the managers with the highest rank.

Comment: Thanks! there should have been a comma between RITDB_employee e and RITDB_manager m. After done that, it worked well. Thanks a lot for your help. I tried so many times but did not manager to make it happen.

Comment: @chen . . . If fixed the `JOIN` conditions.  You should learn proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.